# How to register a wordpress plugin

Tags: discussion, api-key, wordpress

I am about to implement a wordpress plugin to include some of your information in a wordpress blog. In the first version this plugin will display a very limited set of profile information, in further versions more is planned - though I don't know how much time I will be able to spend in the development of this plugin.

My question is: Will only I (as the plugin developer) need to register the application at api.stackexchange.com, or will every single user of that application have to register there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what profile information you need to display.

Basically anything in a user's profile that's public-facing is exposed via the API and requires no action on behalf of the end-user. Starting with v2.0 of the API, you have limited access to some private user information (such as the their full reputation history) through [the OAuth 2.0 methods](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication).

In either case, you will need to register your application [here](https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/register). This will provide you with an API key (essentially required to use the public API) and a client ID/secret (required for the OAuth 2.0 methods).

If you choose to use the OAuth 2.0 methods, your users will be prompted to grant certain permissions to your application, such as read-only access to their private profile information or access to their inbox. The prompt looks something like this:

[image]